# conflicting implementation for `std::vec::Vec<_>` when using auto traits

Tags: generics, rust

I have 2 traits, trait A being a subtrait for trait B:

```
pub trait A {...}
pub trait B {...} //A+some methods
```

And an autotrait for everything not u8:

```
pub auto trait IsNotU8 {}
impl !IsNotU8 for u8 {}
```

An implementation of A for u8:

```
impl A for Vec<u8> {...}
```

And because for all types implementing A, all other methods in B all do nothing I implement B for all types implementing A:

```
impl<K: A> B for K {...} //already implemented here
```

And for a Vec:

```
impl<V: B + IsNotU8> B for Vec<V> {...} //ERROR already implemented
```

I get `` conflicting implementation for `std::vec::Vec<_>` `` even thought the second implementation only works for values that are NOT u8, And the first implementation is only for types implementing A. Since only Vec is implementing A this should not be a problem because that none of the types overlap.

Why am I getting this error? When I don't use the indirection of implementing B for A this works, but with it doesn't. Is this a bug in the compiler when using auto traits?

Comment: Hum, I'm not sure that an auto-trait is the right tool to make what you want, but I'll let someone more experienced to answer.

Comment: I previously used ```pub trait TypeInfo {fn is_u8() -> bool {false}}``` and implemented that for everything, and for u8 having it be overwritten to true. That was not ideal and someone commented on [this](https://users.rust-lang.org/t/how-to-exclude-a-type-from-generic-trait-implementation/26156/7) about auto traits and it seemed quite a lot better.

Comment: https://users.rust-lang.org/t/how-to-exclude-a-type-from-generic-trait-implementation/26156/8 is a better idea IMO. Did you try it? If you're using a nightly compiler, you can just use the specialization feature, BTW.

Comment: Yes that is what I used before, I can try the specialization feature but I cant find anything giving just a simple example. Ill keep looking. But even with that working this code should still compile right? it doesn't have any overlapping implementations.

Comment: The Rust compiler is not (yet?) capable of such inferences. The trait bounds resolution system is currently quite basic. Maybe the chalk project will change that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While there's only an `A` implementation for `Vec<u8>` in the code you showed, it could be added later, and then your `B` implementations would be conflicting. More generally, the compiler will always assume that any missing trait implementation could be added later (except of course your case of an auto trait that is explicitly not implemented for some type).

If you're using nightly features anyway, maybe your problem can be modeled with a const generic function or trait (with a boolean constant)?